# Sum a column of values including letters in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have an input CSV file and need to add all the values in one of the columns, but the values are not plain integers and I'm not sure how to go about it.

The total output should be around 15k, which is the sum of the entire column. I am using pandas dataframe to store .csv file.

Here is the one of the columns in my input `.csv` file:

```
DAMAGE_PROPERTY
0K
0K
2.5K
2.5K
.25K
.25K
2.5K
25K
2.5K
.25K
25K
25K
250K
2.5K
25K
2.5K
2.5K
2.5K
0K
2.5K
.25K
2.5K
25K
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need first remove `K` by [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), then cast to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
print (df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.str.replace('K','').astype(float).sum())
401.0
```

Then can multiple by `1000`:

```
print (df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.str.replace('K','').astype(float).sum() * 1000)
401000.0
```

If need add `K`:

```
print (str(df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.str.replace('K','').astype(float).sum()) + 'K')
401.0K
```

---

EDIT by comment:

If need output in `K`:

```
print (df)
  DAMAGE_PROPERTY
0            2.5K
1            2.5K
2             25M

#create mask where values `M`
mask = df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.str.contains('M')
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: DAMAGE_PROPERTY, dtype: bool

#multiple by 1000 where is mask
df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'] = df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.str.replace(r'[KM]','').astype(float)
df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'] = df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.mask(mask, df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY*1000)
print (df)
   DAMAGE_PROPERTY
0              2.5
1              2.5
2          25000.0

print (df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].sum())
25005.0

print (str(df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].sum()) + 'K' )
25005.0K
```

If need output as number:

```
df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'] = df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.str.replace(r'[KM]','').astype(float)
df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'] = df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.mask(mask, df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY*1000) * 1000
print (df)
   DAMAGE_PROPERTY
0           2500.0
1           2500.0
2       25000000.0

print (df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].sum())
25005000.0
```

EDIT1:

If there are values with `B`:

```
print (df)
  DAMAGE_PROPERTY
0            2.5K
1            2.5B
2             25M

maskM = df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.str.contains('M')
print (maskM)
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: DAMAGE_PROPERTY, dtype: bool

maskB = df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.str.contains('B')
print (maskB)
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: DAMAGE_PROPERTY, dtype: bool

df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'] = df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.str.replace(r'[KMB]','').astype(float)
df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'] = df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.mask(maskM, df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY*1000)
df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'] = df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY.mask(maskB, df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY*1000000)
print (df)
   DAMAGE_PROPERTY
0              2.5
1        2500000.0
2          25000.0

print (df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'])
0          2.5
1    2500000.0
2      25000.0
Name: DAMAGE_PROPERTY, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that there are also some entries like 3.4M(3.4 million) and I want to add them also. So thing is now there are mixed entries like 3K and 3.4M and I want to add them.

Comment: I originally missed the part where OP wanted to *keep* the letters, instead of chopping them off. You get my +1.

Comment: Ahh. I found some entries like 6B also. I am sorry it is very huge file so I am missing some entries. Your code is working for me for K and M entries. Can you please tell me what should I do for B entries? I guess we need to convert all the entries either in billions or thousands. What say?

Comment: Yes, you need another mask. Give me a second.

Comment: I am getting error as "ValueError: could not convert string to float: ". Is this because of some null entry? Please guide

Comment: Without data it is problem answer. Is possible share your csv?

Comment: It is 1GB csv file. I can see that there are some entries with only values like 0,2 i.e preceded by no M,B or K. Is this error is occurring because of these entries?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118179/discussion-between-chinmaykelkar-and-jezrael).

Comment: H is also there as hundreds. I need to add one more mask for that

Comment: Ok, I give you solution for it. I try find something faster, give me a time.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Following this pattern, you can add "B" for billions. And do nothing for values that dont have "K", or "M".

```
def chgFormat(x):
        newFormat = 0
        if   x[-1] == 'K': newFormat = float(x[:-1])
        elif x[-1] == 'H': newFormat = float(x[:-1])/10    
        elif x[-1] == 'M': newFormat = float(x[:-1])*1000
        elif x[-1] == 'B': newFormat = float(x[:-1])*1000000    
        return newFormat

print str(sum(df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].dropna().apply(chgFormat)))+'K'
print str(sum(df['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].dropna().apply(chgFormat))/1000)+'M''

Results:
401.0K
0.401M
```

Use this: if there are NaNs:

```
    print str(sum(df3['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].dropna().apply(chgFormat)))+'K'
    print str(sum(df3['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].dropna().apply(chgFormat))/1000)+'M'
```

Edited #3:

```
    print sum(df3['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].dropna().apply(chgFormat))
```

Comment: What should I do for NaN values?

Comment: Edited again, If you see the pattern, its now just a math problem. which is based on using K, M or B. or H

Comment: Your code is working good for me. But problem is I am getting datatype of 'DAMAGE_PROPERTY' as object. So I am not able to perform query like "DAMAGE_PROPERTY>=0" as DAMAGE_PROPERTY is of object type. But I want it as float type. I tried using .astypes(float) but it didn't work . Please let me know if you have solution for it.

Comment: Yes there is a solution for that.  '401.0K' is an object. '401.0' is a float.  Dont do  "str()"  or "+ 'K'" and you have floats.  You should go through a python tutorial that is basic python coding.  You should mark this answer correct if this is the solution  you are using.

Comment: Can you please check datatype of df3['DAMAGE_PROPERTY] after applying function you have written? Is it still showing object to you?

Comment: You need to ask another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118362/discussion-between-chinmaykelkar-and-merlin).

Comment: You need to go through a  tutorial  Here is one.   https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/IntroductionToPythonSolutions.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with pandas/dataframe, but you can use simple Python logic for this. Assuming your file follows the same pattern of having the `"K"` as the last character in each line, consider the following:

```
>>> float("2.0K"[:-1])
2.0
>>> float("2.0M"[:-1])
2.0
```

You can use the bit above on each line. For example:

```
# assuming you've read the contents into a list called "lines"
values = []
for s in lines:
    try:
        values.append(float(s[:-1])))
    except ValueError:
        # found something else; log it or something
        pass
```

Finally, you just add them together with Python's built-in `sum` function:

```
total = sum(values)
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that there are also some entries like 3.4M(3.4 million) and I want to add them also. So thing is now there are mixed entries like 3K and 3.4M and I want to add them.

Comment: @chinmaykelkar: See the updated post. If you use `float("2.0K"[:-1])` then it doesn't matter whether you have a "K" or an "M" or something else at the end. You can use list notation/slicing in strings and this simply cuts of the last char.

Comment: @chinmaykelkar: Ah, I missed that you wanted to add the trailing letters. I thought you wanted to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write these functions:

```
import re

mapper = dict(k=1e3, K=1e3,
              m=1e6, M=1e6,
              b=1e9, B=1e9)
pot = ('K', 'M', 'B')

def revmap(value):
    powers_of_K = int(np.log10(value) // 3)
    if powers_of_K > len(pot): 
        suffix = pot[-1]
    else:
        suffix = pot[powers_of_K - 1]

    k = mapper[suffix]
    f = ("%f" % (value / k)).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
    return f + suffix

def sum_with_units(s):
    regex = r'(?P<value>.*)(?P<unit>k|m)'
    s_ = s.str.extract(regex, expand=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    summed = (s_.value.astype(float) * s_.unit.map(mapper)).sum()
    return revmap(summed)

sum_with_units(df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY)

'401K'
```

take:

```
df_plus = pd.concat([df for _ in range(2500)])

sum_with_units(df.DAMAGE_PROPERTY)

'1.0025B'
```